# How to reuse components among multiple viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been going through an IOS project, in which I found a same set of code used in multiple `viewController`.

Example:

**xxxxViewController.m**

```
UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 133, 62)];
logoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
[self.view addSubview:logoImageView];
```

**yyyyViewController.m**

```
UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 133, 62)];
logoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
[self.view addSubview:logoImageView];
```

Similarly for `3+ viewController.m` files. Here is my question, how can we reuse this piece of code throughout the entire project being new to IOS I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you want to extract the code into a more reusable form, depends completely on the nature of the view controllers.

If all the view controllers are displaying a similar concept that all include a logo I would recommend creating a view controller superclass:

```
@interface MyViewControllerWithLogo : UIViewController
@end

@implementation
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 133, 62)];
    logoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
    [self.view addSubview:logoImageView];
}
@end
```

If the view controllers are displaying different concepts, but they contain views for the same sort of object, you can create a UIView subclass and use that wherever you need the view with the logo:

```
@interface MyViewWithLogo : UIView
@end

@implementation
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setupViews];
    }
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setupViews];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupViews
{
    UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 133, 62)];
    logoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
    [self.view addSubview:logoImageView];
}
@end
```

Other common methods are not going to really save you any code and only make it more complicated. Another method would include using a presenter object that takes the view that you want to add the logo to that you would instantiate in each view controller.

```
@interface LogoPresenter : NSObject
    - (void)addLogoToView:(UIView *)view;
@end

@implementation
- (void)addLogoToView:(UIView *)view
{
     UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 133, 62)];
    logoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
    [view addSubview:logoImageView];
}
@end

@implementation AViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    LogoPresenter *presenter = [LogoPresenter new];
    [presenter addLogoToView:self.view];
}
@end
```

The big thing you need to think about is do subclasses in any particular place make logical sense. They are the highest form of [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) so use subclassing with caution. If subclasses don't make sense, go with the presenter method.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for showing other sides.  currently I'm away of my mac, I will try it out refactoring the code and let you know.  More new things learned from your answer, need to google it :)

Comment: Glad to help :). I guess I just wanted to stress that keeping an understandable mental model of the code is the highest priority if you want maintainable code. Straightforward mental models make it much easier for other people or yourself in a few months to get into the code and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a LogoImageView class (subclass of UIImageView) that is configured how you'd like to use it. Then you can add it everywhere you need.

---

*LogoImageView.h:*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LogoImageView : UIImageView

+ (UIImageView *)defaultView;

@end
```

*LogoImageView.m:*

```
@implementation LogoImageView

- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 133, 62)];
    if (self){
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (UIImageView *)defaultView {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

@end
```

And you can use it everywhere like this (make sure you import `LogoImageView.h`):

```
[view addSubview:[LogoImageView defaultView]];
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot..  one more question; can I change it like utilities having multiple reusable components as well functions similar to `UIImageView` within this `LogoImageView` class?

Comment: I'd say subclass each component you'd want to reuse, that's what I do in most projects. Alternatively you could create a single class (Factory) that constructs all components you need (buttons, imageviews, etc...), but I'd say that approach is a bit more messy.

Comment: An additional point I should make, is that it would probably not be best to set the x and y coordinates of a frame in such a default image view. The x and y coordinates most likely depend upon the dimensions of the container of the image view. It's better to override `layoutSubviews` in the superview to position components.

Comment: That right, I also checked other reusable components with varied x,y positions..  Surely I will keep all your points and give a try on refactoring the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create UIView category which can add subview:

```
-(void)addLogo {
    UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 133, 62)];
    logoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
    [self addSubview:logoImageView];
}
```

and whenever you want to add logo you can call:

```
[self.view addLogo];
```

Comment: This means like creating a function and calling it whenever I need it.  Right?  +1 though a valid point I wish to have something more efficient way.

Comment: No I mean category - it's a way you can add new method/s to existing classes. Google it, it's very easy to create it.

Comment: I don't think there is a strong use case to add to the UIView class.  Better to create a separate class to add the logo so you don't have to worry about potentially overriding an existing method or conflicting with other libraries you may end up adding.

Comment: @drewag, All of the answer are about subclassing so I wanted to show another way to do that.

Comment: @Greg Ya that's a good point. There are definitely lots of different methods to get this done and it is great to present lots of them and discuss the pros and cons of each. I think this method is one of the quickest and simplest. It just has the downside of potentially conflicting with future versions of UIView or with other categories (especially if people are not familiar with how categories work).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a superclass called LogoViewController and make the logo imageView a property of it. Then move all the setup code to viewDidLoad, or wherever is appropriate.  Then all the other view controllers can subclass it and when they call [super viewDidLoad] they will get the logo setup code.